# How to clean large area of marble

Tags: cleaning, marble

I am trying to help someone who has moved into an old house which has marble floor (huge tiles ~4' x4'). The marble is dirty and stained all round (looks like dirt or dirt on oil which has 'baked' over time) - continuously around the skirt of the house (from the base of the skirt to up to 2 inches) and randomly like so :

[image]
[image]

I made a mixture of cooking soda and hydrogen peroxide and it has helped git rid of the corner stains. Because of the nature of this mixture, I can't pour it in a spray bottle as the soda will block the pipe. I have about 3000 square foot to go so taking a pad and scrubbing such a large area is out of the question. What is the easiest way for me to get this marble clean ? It will be very helpful if I can make the cleaner at home.

Comment: pressure washer maybe.  in combination with a shop vac to suck up the water right after it hits the floor

Comment: @jsotola, I'd be wary of a pressure washer.  Marble is very soft and porous.  For a pressure washer to help, it would be likely to cut the surface and leave permanent ruts.  A steam cleaner might help.  Same with various chemical cleaners.  But research any cleaners beforehand as many will etch or stain marble.

Answer (score 3):

Bar keepers friend is a decent idea.
Do not pressure wash!
Marble is soft and you will ruin it. My advice it to call a carpet/floor cleaning company, or better yet a marble/granite installer.  Even if they do not clean themselves they will tell you what to do or where to go.
Marble is soft and will soak in certain liquids badly.  Once you get it cleaned, which should probably be done professionally, have it sealed.  It isn't 100%, but it will help a lot.
If you can afford it, get it professionally done by a trusted organization.  Be careful of handymen and others who do not specialize in it.  In the long run a professional cleaner will save you a ton of money and frustration.
If you want really cheap and easy, recover it and wait until you can afford the professional.

Answer (score 2):

Marble is often successfully cleaned and polished using oxalic acid. There are inexpensive household products that contain oxalic acid or you should be able to by bulk powder at a tile/marble shop. You mix with water to a soupy paste and scrub it with a brush, then rinse it off. I would recommend removing gross contamination by washing first, then the acid scrub, then rinse well.

I have used this stuff (not an endorsement):

[image]